# Why do the Cygwin installer update so frequently?

Tags: cygwin

I use and love cygwin, but every few weeks it notifies me that a new installer is available and I should use it to get the latest bugfixes. But I find this quite annoying because of my company policy, where downloading, installing and running a new .EXE file is a bit of a process due to paranoid company monitoring software.

I am just curious why the installer updates so frequently and what will happen if I don't update it. It is after all just an installer - all it does is it downloads updated packages and installs them (or rather, that is what I believe all it is doing). I do not understand why such a simple tool should have so many fixes/updates over time. If I don't update the installer, will I miss out on updates to the cygwin packages themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the same cygwin version since years now and not faced any issues.
If the application is working as expected then you dont need an update unless you face some trouble or you are migrating to a new windows Os which might have some compatibility issues.
**Note** : There is no guarantee that there will not be any problems with applying updates and also the cygwin faq section says that after updates issues  should be reported to the project or product supplier for remedial action.

https://cygwin.com/faq/

Answer (score 1):

The changes in `Setup` are usually to improve the functionality or correct some
issue.

See relative Announce:
https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2021-April/010021.html

Most of the time, previous version continues to work fine.
Broke of compatibility is very `rare`.